trigger a node script on file upload
I use Multer on my API endpoint to upload a single file to my server (and it works well).
let uploadFile = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: { fileSize: maxSize },
}).single("file");

The api endpoint is the following:
const upload = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await uploadFile(req, res);

    if (req.file == undefined) {
      return res.status(400).send({ message: "Please upload a file!" });
    }

    //here I want tocall the file processing endpoint asynchronously
    res.status(200).send({
      message: "Uploaded the file successfully: " + req.file.originalname,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);

    if (err.code == "LIMIT_FILE_SIZE") {
      return res.status(500).send({
        message: "File size cannot be larger than 2MB!",
      });
    }

    res.status(500).send({
      message: `Could not upload the file: ${req.file.originalname}. ${err}`,
    });
  }
};

While I am sending 200 back to the client I'd like also to call another endpoint to process the uploaded file further. I can use fetch for that but in this case I have to wait for the file to be processed before returning 200 to the client for file upload.
Is there a way to call the second endpoint without waiting for the response for the file processing? File processing can take some seconds to be performed. The file processing API will notify the user about the result of its processing using FAYE so no need for the UI to wait for that.

Yes, by just calling it and not awaiting the outcome? Once you call res it resolves...
